# ChannelPipelineCoverage is deprectated. Is there a drop-in replacement?

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to eliminate warnings produced by a library I have to work with.

I've bumped the netty version for the library to 3.5.4.Final. However, the ChannelPipelineCoverage annotation appear to be deprecated.

My question is: Is there any easy drop-in replacement, or does this require extensive coding?
If so, I would love some references on how to start!

Is a class without @ChannelHandler.Shareable() the same as a class with @ChannelPipelineCoverage("one")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you have figured it out by now, but the name has been changed to "Sharable", as described:NETTY-283:

Logged Change Request [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NETTY-283): and 
some mailing archive [here](http://mail-archive.ow2.org/accord-commits/2012-03/msg00000.html): suggesting to use: import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandler.Sharable, to set the reference in your Java class.